Strategies for Updating Dependencies in a Mature Flutter App: Resolving Conflicts and Navigating Discontinued Packages
I am currently tasked with updating a mature Flutter application from version 2.0.5 to the latest release. However, I am encountering significant challenges due to tightly coupled dependencies within the application.
The application has been developed over the span of four years, and as a solo developer, I find myself navigating through a maze of dependencies where updating one package breaks another. Additionally, some of the packages utilized in the application have been discontinued, further complicating the update process.
Furthermore, I've noticed that certain packages are interdependent, with one requiring a specific version of another package that conflicts with the version required by another part of the application.
Given this scenario, I'm seeking advice on how to effectively manage these dependencies and navigate through this complex update process. Specifically, I'm looking for strategies or best practices to:
Handle conflicting dependencies without compromising the stability of the application.
Address dependencies on discontinued packages and find suitable alternatives.
Manage interdependent packages that require conflicting versions of the same dependency.

Any insights, experiences, or recommended approaches from developers who have encountered similar challenges would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
During the process of updating packages in my Flutter application, I encountered a roadblock where Flutter itself required a specific version of a package, while another package within my application depended on a different version of the same package. This situation halted my progress and posed a significant challenge to proceed with the update.
Specifically, when attempting to align with the requirements of the Flutter framework, I found that it mandated a particular version of a package, let's call it "Package X". However, a different package within my application relied on a distinct version of "Package X" to function properly.

Actually dependencies is some how may lead to a  deadlock , for example you can depend on a plugin that no longer maintained , which conflict with another new plugin you still used , so my opinion is , if the plugin you depend on isn't often updated , you may need to fork it and update it's dependency.
It might sounds like a headache but when you have very old plugin it's become a bottle neck to use new things or even update flutter it s;ef
